# Insert Where Not Exists not working

Tags: teradata

It's a simple select statement where i'm trying to insert any new updates with a timestamp. For some reason it just doesn't seem to work. Everything looks fine but when I'm testing the query, it doesn't seem to work.

```
INSERT sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht 
SELECT id, hotel_id, room_type_id, date__, stop_sell, 
   inventory_count, created, modified__, 
   current_timestamp as snapshot_ts FROM user_gp.inv_room_type_inventory
WHERE    NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT id, hotel_id, room_type_id, date__, stop_sell, 
      inventory_count, created, modified__ 
   FROM sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht
  );
```

Could someone please assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you are not writing the query right. Basically you are asking to insert values when there is no record in your 'sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht' table. So, in other words, even if there is only one record exists in 'sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht', it won't insert anything.

I assume you wanted to check if the id you are trying to insert exists in 'sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht' table. In such case you'll need to add a where clause inside your not exists condition, so, it would look like:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id, hotel_id, room_type_id, date__, stop_sell, inventory_count, created, modified__ 
FROM sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht
WHERE id = user_gp.inv_room_type_inventory.id);
```

Comment: got it. it's mroe like a correlated subquery.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an Insert/Select using NOT EXISTS you better go for MERGE, just one access to the target table and you can do both INSERTs and UPDATEs in one statement. Have a look at the [manuals](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_151K/ch03.023.159.html).

I don't know about your logic, but it will look like:

```
MERGE INTO sandbox.inv_room_type_inventory_snpsht AS tgt
USING 
 (
   SELECT id, hotel_id, room_type_id, date__, stop_sell, 
      inventory_count, created, modified__, 
      current_timestamp as snapshot_ts 
   FROM user_gp.inv_room_type_inventory
 ) AS src
ON src.id = tgt.id
AND .....
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
VALUES (src.id, src.hotel_id, src.room_type_id,
        src.date__, src.stop_sell, 
        src.inventory_count, src.created, src.modified__,
        src.snapshot_ts
       )
 ;
```