# whether it is possible to overwrite the result of the UNION operation to the name of the first table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following question. Can the result of a UNION operation on two tables overwrite the name of 1 table.

So I have

```
SELECT * FROM table1

UNION

SELECT * FROM table 2
```

I want this result of the UNION operation to overwrite table1. Is it possible ?

Comment: Sounds pretty easy to test...

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean... Show us some sample table data and the expected result - a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite" - try and give an example  of table 1 and table 2 rows and the expected result

Comment: Rather than overwrite all the data, can you simply insert when not exists, such as something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515982/insert-where-not-exists-not-working). Basically, insert table2 data that doesn't exist in table1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table1 and table2 have the same columns:

```
declare @tbl table (DEFINE_SAME_COLUMNS_AS_table1);

insert into @tbl
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2

delete table1

insert into table1
select * from @tbl
```

Comment: This question is tagged with [teradata] DBMS but you have supplied [sql-server] syntax. (The [sql] tag is generic for any SQL-based question.)